# Twilio Flex Webchat welcome message

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to change the default WelcomeMessage of Twilio Flex Webchat. I´m running webchat from npm package.
Below is my webchat-appConfig.js code. When I execute it, the webchat loads but the WelcomeMessage doesn´t change.

```
var appConfig = {
    componentProps: {
        MainContainer: {
            height: '80%'
        },
        MainHeader: {
            showTitle: true,
            titleText: 'Alfredo Prueba',
            imageUrl: '',
        },
        MessagingCanvas: {
            PredefinedMessage: {
                body: 'Funciona',
                authorName: 'Alfredo',
                isFromMe: false,
            },
            memberDisplayOptions: {
                yourDefaultName: 'Tú',
                yourFriendlyNameOverride: false,
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override [`PredefinedMessage`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/webchat/configuration#predefinedmessage).

You can do this via:

- the `componentProps` section in the configuration object, or
- the [defaultProps API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/webchat/configuration#react-default-props-api), in your case this would be `FlexWebChat.MessagingCanvas.defaultProps.predefinedMessage`

Comment: It doesnt works with componentProps. Edited is my componentProps configuration. It should show a message: "Funciona", but instead sends the standard welcome message.

Comment: @A.Asensio your example code shows `PredefinedMessage` but the property should be `predefinedMessage` with a lowercase "p".

Comment: Still not working with 'predefinedMessage'

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked with [defaultProps](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/webchat/configuration#predefinedmessage)

Here is what I used: `Twilio.FlexWebChat.MessagingCanvas.defaultProps.predefinedMessage.body = "Your Welcome Message";`